# Access the Message Inbox and read Contents in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to write a program for Windows Phone 7.5/8. My concept is, The appa should automatically read the incoming SMS, extract the data and notify of important things to the user. Is it possible? Like, it should read the message containing the total balance from you bank and notify you when the total amount goes below certain limit. Is it feasible or possible in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not currently possible to intercept an incoming SMS or read past messages in the public Windows Phone SDK.